# Typesetting a flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf

The MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{> = stealth'}

\tikzset{%
  /tikz/flowchart/.style       = {text height = height("A"), text depth = depth("g"), row sep = 5ex},
  /tikz/flowchart/begin/.style = {flowchart, draw, rectangle, rounded corners = .5em},
  /tikz/flowchart/cmd/.style   = {flowchart, draw, rectangle},
  /tikz/flowchart/cond/.style  = {flowchart, draw, diamond, aspect = 2.7},
  /tikz/flowchart/end/.style   = {flowchart, draw, rectangle, rounded corners = .5em},
  /tikz/flowchart/io/.style    = {flowchart, draw, trapezium, trapezium left angle = 60,  trapezium right angle = 120},
  /tikz/flowchart/flow/.style  = {draw, ->}
}


\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix [flowchart]
{
  \node [flowchart/cmd] (A1) {Anweisung 1}; \\
  \node [flowchart/cmd] (A2) {Anweisung 2}; \\
                                            \\
  \node [flowchart/cmd] (An) {Anweisung n}; \\
};

\coordinate (B)  at ($(A1) + (0, 0.8)$);
\coordinate (E)  at ($(An) - (0, 0.8)$);

\begin{scope} [flowchart/flow]
  \draw (B)  -- (A1);
  \draw (A1) -- (A2);
  \draw (A2) -- (An) node [midway, fill = white] {$\vdots$};
  \draw (An) -- (E);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

yields the following result:

[image: Output of the MWE]

Here are my questions:

1. Is there an easy way of drawing the interrupted line using TikZ (without the node)?
2. How can I remove the margins in order to achieve a tight bounding box?
3. Is there anything else that can be simplified or improved in the code?

Comment: If you use @Zarko's answer but set `\documentclass[border=0mm]{standalone} `, you should also get your question 2, if I understood it properly. The same should work in your code, if you replace your `\documentclass{scrartcl `

Answer (score 3):

With `tikz` package using `chains` library instead of `matrix`:

```
%\documentclass{scrartcl}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}
\tikzset{%
   node distance = 3ex,
     start chain,
     base/.style = {draw, text height = height("A"), text depth = depth("g")},
    begin/.style = {base, rectangle, rounded corners = .5em},
      cmd/.style = {base},
     cond/.style = {base, diamond, aspect = 2.7},
      end/.style = {base, rounded corners = .5em},
       io/.style = {base, trapezium, trapezium stretches body, 
                    trapezium left angle = 60,  trapezium right angle = 120},
               > = Stealth,
    flow/.style  = {draw, semithick, ->}
        }

\begin{document}
%\fbox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=going below},
                  every join/.style ={flow}]
\node [cmd,join] (A1) {Anweisung 1};
\node [cmd,join] (A2) {Anweisung 2};
\coordinate (aux1);
\coordinate (aux2);
\node [cmd,join] (An) {Anweisung n};
\coordinate[join] (aux3);
    \end{scope}
\draw[semithick]       (chain-2) -- (aux1);
\draw[semithick, densely dotted] (aux1) -- (aux2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
%     }
\end{document}
```

Above MWE show possible solution for the first and third question. Second is unfortunately unclear to me.

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. Is it possible, however, to use a custom decoration for the line between (A2) and (A2) instead of the aux nodes?

Comment: How about more complex flow charts? Is positioning using `right of`, `left of` etc. better than using a matrix of nodes?

Comment: As for my second question: Even without the option `border = 3 mm` of the document class `standalone` there is a white margin around the whole image. Where does is come from? How can it be removed?

Comment: This not happen with my MWE. Tested.

Answer (score 2):

A proposition with `pstricks`, defining relevant nodes in a simple `tabular` environment and linking them with node connections:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}%
\newcommand{\chartnode}[2]{\psDefBoxNodes{#1}{\fcolorbox{LightSlateGray}{white}{#2}}}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{4}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\pnode{u} \\[-3ex]
\chartnode{A1}{Anweisung 1} \\
\chartnode{A2}{Anweisung 2}\\[3ex]
\chartnode{An}{Anweisung n} \\[-5ex]
\pnode{d}
\end{tabular}
\psset{linewidth=1pt, linecolor=LightSlateGray, linejoin=1, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12}
\pcline(u)(A1:tC)
\pcline(A1:bC)(A2:tC)
\pcline(A2:bC)(An:tC)\ncput*[nrot=:U]{$\color{LightSlateGray}\ldots$}
\pcline(An:bC)(d)
}

\end{document}
```

[image]